# Best way to create defence(withdraw) algorthim libgdx?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, steering-behaviors

I have created user body and enemy body. Enemy body uses the steering behavior created by gdx AI. User body have it own control inputprocessor. World doesnt have gravity.

Enemy body arrives the user body and collision happens by linearvelocity.  So enemy body only attacks even if it is getting more damage. I just want to declare a way to withdraw and find a safe place when it get more damage  then again attacks when it get enough distinct.

So What do you suggest for My game ?

I already got some idea as Path finder but i am not sure how to use it.

Which algorithm I need to user ?